# Output TX Power with complex impedances

Tags: power, impedance, sdr

I'm developing an application with my software defined radio (SDR) Board and it is very critical that I have some control over the actual power I am transmitting at every time.

In order to do this, I have first measured the impedance of the TX antenna port and unfortunately it is not a purely 50ohm impedance. In fact we can treat it as a complex Z = R + jX impedance, with the values of R and X known.

Knowing this, and assuming that I'm transmitting pulses with voltage U(t) well known, my question is the following:

I believe that if Z = 50 ohm, the total power P(t) of the signal would simply be (right?):

$$P = \frac{1}{t_1-t_0}\int_{t0}^{t1} \frac{U^2(t)}{50} \, dt $$

In general, since U(t) is known, I don't believe that I have to pursue any approximations in computing that pulse power.

However, if the impedance is complex, as it is the case, what is the relation between transmitted power and transmitted voltage? I mean, am I simply interested in the absolute of Z, i.e:

$$P = \frac{1}{t_1-t_0}\int_{t0}^{t1} \frac{U^2(t)}{|Z|} \, dt $$

or am I interested in the Real part of P only?

Comment: how do you measure the impedance of a TX port?!

Comment: (that's a very serious question here: Interpretation of the results really depends  which operational state your PA to be in and how you measured.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have used a VNA and observed the result in a smith chart. As expected the impedance measured in accordance to the center frequency of the channel, therefore I registed the impedance value for the center frequency of interest.

Comment: ok, but HOW did you use the VNA and in what operation mode was the SDR at the time? The impedance seen when trying to *sink* energy into the output of an amplifier depends on what the amplifier is doing at that time.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I really wasn't aware of such criteria. I simply configured the SDR to the intended channel frequency and then performed the impedance measurement. I was not transmitting. I'm really not sure on how to proceed now. All I wanted to do was to make a calibration table that would tell me at every configuration of TX antenna gain and digital IQ word what was the power being sent. What do you suggest? How is my impedance approach wrong?

Comment: well, if your amplifier is active, then its job is to generate a specific current on its output (proportional to the input); if the amplifier worked perfectly, that would look like a ground short that gets transformed by the not-perfectly-matched transmission lines between amp and 50Ω connector; however, amps aren't perfect. Things get complicated pretty quickly, and frankly, you don't care about the actual impedance at all. If you have a VNA, you probably also have a way to measure output power – simply do that and generate a "digital amplitude -> output power" table. Not much magic in that!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Initially that was my approach, but then, if my RX Port impedance is not at 50 ohm neither, and I want to transmit from TX to RX, then how do I know what power is being actually received at RX?

Comment: By calibrating with a source of known power.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That does make sense and I believe I was wrong to start considering the impedance approach. Indeed what you are describing was my initial approach to the problem. I just stopped because I wasn't sure about what was the correct way to calibrate RX in that way. I.e., I wasn't sure on how to measure the power from a frequency generator with RX. Should I make an acquisition and take the vrms of the results? Should I perform the abs(fft) of the results and take the amplitude spectral density or even squared it and get the psd? Can you enlight me with a protocol? Thanks

Comment: the energy in the DFT is the same as in the time signal (Parseval's theorem!) So, simply get your source of known power, acquire samples (make sure you're not damaging your receiver end!! Most SDR RX are very sensitive, and can be damaged by the powers their own TX can produce!), square and average them: that's your "digital power".